# What is the difference between max & greatest (min & least)?

Tags: db2, max

Sql in db2 works with both max() function and greatest() function, but I was wondering if both are put there in the language, there must be a difference between the two?

Comment: @WarrenT google it yourself, the answer doesn't come up. I'll refer to db2 documentation from now on as a source. I'm a beginner here, don't assume everyone is in the same place as you are

Comment: Well, if you want an authoritative answer, what should be the first place one should check for the most reliable answer?  Twitter?  Facebook?  Various blogs or forums returned by Google?  Or go to the definitive source, the reference manual?  Is the answer not obvious?  We don't mind helping beginners, but we do have guidelines on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a question, which start by asking that you show thorough research.  I apologize if I sounded harsh.  We were all beginners once, and we live and learn (hopefully ;)  And now you've got a link to the manual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Direct quote from the [DB2 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-greatest):

> The `GREATEST` scalar function is a synonym for the `MAX` scalar function.

Answer (score 10):

MIN/MAX aggregate over the same attribute in multiple rows, while GREATER/LEAST choose the value from a number of expressions for just one row.

Comment: This is true for MySQL and PostgreSQL, but I think it's different for DB2. `MIN` and `MAX` can be used for either scalars or aggregates (`GREATEST` and `LEAST` are only used for scalars).